# Keeping debug outputs for 12 hours?

Tags: android, logging, android-logcat

For one of my android projects I need to collect some debug data over a 12 to 24 hour timespan. Writing to the logcat is not a solution, as it won't keep logs that long. Is there any better way than logging manually to a file? Some kind of API for this "long time" logging?

Thanks for any hint on this :-)

Comment: any logging API is more than likely going to just write to a file somewhere

Comment: What won't "keep logs that long"? It's not clear what the question is: logging has to write *somewhere*, either a file, a DB, an endpoint, etc. Pick one and implement.

Comment: Log entries done using android logcat api e.g. Log.d(..) won't be kept forever as the log buffers are circular. So the question is: Does Android provide some way to log to a file using the logcat API or similar?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution might be writing the debug logs to a permanent file on a pc.

This will copy the contents of the log and then exit.

```
adb logcat -d > logcat.txt
```

If you want to continue writing to the file as new log output is created, then remove the -d, and it will continue copying to file.

```
adb logcat > logcat.txt
```

Comment: thank you, but my android phone won't be connected to a pc during this period ):

Answer (score 0):

What about writing your own Log class, a wrapper that will use log4j for file logging and android.util.log for native logcat.

```
public class Log
{
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MAIN_LOGGER"); 

    // info
    public static void i(String tag, String message)
    {
        // logcat
        android.util.Log.i(tag, message);

        // log4j
        logger.info("[" + tag + "] " + message);
    }

    // TODO other levels
}
```

log4j.properties

```
# [...]
log4j.logger.MAIN_LOGGER = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
# TODO improve this
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/sdcard/log.out
```

In your app, instead of using the regular Log class, use your custom one.